# "Aufheben" vs. "aufnehmen" for picking something up

Tags: word-usage, verb

I want to say, "I pick the baby up off the floor," but I'm having trouble deciding whether *aufheben* or *aufnehmen* is the correct word.

> Ich nehme das Baby vom Boden auf

or

> Ich hebe das Baby vom Boden auf

or something else entirely?

Can one of these words be used to talk about picking up any object??

Comment: Using "aufheben" sounds like you take the baby from the ground and hold it in your hands, not knowing what to do with it. It can be translated by "to lift something". Aufnehmen is much deeper, for example it can be used to translate "to admit someone to something", to assimilate, to take into your pocket, to record on tape, etc. In a text both could be correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both sentences are correct and will be understood.

`aufnehmen` has a more general meaning (e.g. Das Auto kann 9 Leute aufnehmen.) and seems a little bit misplaced in this context.

`aufheben` is rather used concerning objects, so one *might* think, that you objectified the baby.

Better alternative would be `hochnehmen`:

> Ich nehme das Baby vom Boden hoch.

Also possible, but with a connotation of short term, would be `hochheben`:

> Ich hebe das Baby vom Boden hoch (, damit ich den Boden saugen kann).

Comment: You could also leave out the 'hoch' in the last sentence...

Answer (score 1):

If you pick up something physical off the ground, I think **aufheben** is the word for it.
**Aufnehmen** is very broad and can mean all kinds of things. One translation is **to pick up**, but that is more **to pick up** a discussion at where it left off or other more abstract things.
The baby example sounds weird either way. I think that **aufnehmen** does indeed make it sound less like an object but it is a weird sentence anyway.
I think a mom would "heben ihr Baby hoch".